# EF CF Migration for Default Value of column

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

In one of my projects I've used a EF Code First aproach and used to create new migrations by `Add-Migration MyMigration` command. Now I need to create a migration which will set the default value for property in one of my classes. I've tried to add attribute `[DefaultValue("true")]` and then genereated a new migration for it with `Add-Migration` but this migration is empty. It seems that EF did not notice any changes. Is there any way to create a migration only for setting up default value for one of the class properties?

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided any structure of your class that you want create a migration on.... So I am posting a migration on a demo class..

**If your created migration is empty then try putting below code there**

```
public override void Up()
{
    AlterColumn("dbo.YourTableName", "ColumnName", c => c.String(defaultValueSql: "Khaled Maruf"));
}
```

**IF your table column has past data in it then try using the below one**

```
public override void Up()
{
    Sql("UPDATE dbo.YourTableName SET ColumnName = 'Khaled Maruf' WHERE ColumnName IS NULL");
    AlterColumn("dbo.YourTableName", "ColumnName", c => c.String(defaultValueSql: "Khaled Maruf"));
}
```

Hope this helps....

Comment: Thanks! But is there any way to create this automaticaly by Add-Migrations command?

Comment: I don't know about that... sorry for not being able  to help you on that @Anton